# how does the compare method works with the return values? in Comparator class?

Tags: java, collections, compare, comparator

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Data>(){
          public int compare(Data obj1, Data obj2){
              return (obj1.value > obj2.value) ? -1: (obj1.value > obj2.value) ? 1:0 ;
          }
    });
```

I'm using this code to sort a list in not ascending order and this method works but I don't understand how it works internally.

How does this code work with return values `-1,1,0`?

why does this method compare the same thing `(obj1.value > obj2.value)` twice?

list is an `ArrayList` type reference variable in which contains `Data` type objects and the Data class looks like below

```
private static class Data{
    private String key;
    private int value;

    public Data(String key, int value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: The comparison is buggy, one of them should be `<`

Comment: If you're using Java 8, the `Comparator` class has a bunch of built-in static functions you can apply.

Comment: Right now it's impossible for your compare to return 1. It may just be a coincidence that it worked.

Comment: It doesn't work, so your question is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison method is improperly coded, as a commenter said. The first comparison presumably should have been `<`, not `>`. If you were to read the Javadocs for `Comparator<T>` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html you would see that it is supposed to return a negative value if the first argument precedes the second, 0 if they are equivalent, and a positive value if the the first argument follows the second. That is not what your code does.

Comment: And 'Comparator' is an interface, not a class.